# How can we stop spring boot data cassandra from connecting to localhost?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra

We are using Spring data - cassandra and when we run the application without providing configuration, spring boot tries to connect to localhost. Is there a way to stop spring boot from auto connecting?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple ways to achieve that but none of them is just a boolean flag:

1. Remove the Cassandra dependency, if you can afford dependency exclusion
2. Provide `@Lazy` `Session`/`CassandraTemplate` `@Bean`'s yourself:

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class MyCassandraConfiguration extends CassandraDataAutoConfiguration {

       public MyCassandraConfiguration(BeanFactory beanFactory, CassandraProperties properties, Cluster cluster, Environment environment) {
           super(beanFactory, properties, cluster, environment);
       }

       @Override
       @Bean
       @Lazy
       public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session(CassandraConverter converter) throws Exception {
           return super.session(converter);
       }

       @Bean
       @Lazy
       @Override
       public CassandraTemplate cassandraTemplate(Session session, CassandraConverter converter) throws Exception {
           return super.cassandraTemplate(session, converter);
       }
   }
   ```

   Lazy beans are initialized the first time they are used.
3. [Exclude](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html) the [CassandraAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.java). Depending on your setup even more auto-configurations. This approach is rather invasive as required dependencies might get not initialized.